# How do we know $\sqrt{-1}$ exists?

Tags: complex-numbers

I recently was going through one of real analysis book where in a chapter, they proved that $\sqrt{2}$ exists. It makes me think that we can't just assume that a certain number exists, and we must prove its existence from the previous results that are available to us. It makes me think how do we know that $\sqrt{-1}$ exists using the postulates and all the results we know before talking about complex numbers. How do we establish a logical "connection" between $i$ and our previously known facts?

Comment: If you are asking whether the equation $z^2=-1$ has a solution in the complex numbers, set $z=i$ and compute $z^2$ and you are done. It's as simple as that, just like proving that $x^2=4$ has a solution in the real numbers. But if that's not what you are asking, perhaps you can clarify your question.

Comment: @LeeMosher how do we know such a solution exists?

Comment: @zaemon_23 How do you define the complex numbers? First you need a formal definition. Otherwise, the question makes no sense.

Comment: How do we know $-1$ exists?  How do we know $1/2$ exists? In each case, they do exist—by construction—in some number systems but don’t in others. As @LeeMosher suggests, a great way to think about it is in terms of which equations do or don’t have solutions in any particular system. That will get you from the integers, through the rationals and reals, to the complex numbers.

Comment: @Mark we define complex numbers as numbers that have a real component as well as an imaginary unit. But for that imaginary unit, we need help of $i$. So is the existence of $i$ a postulate?

Comment: So it seems that what you *really* want to know is how complex numbers are constructed concretely,  and how $i$ is defined under such a concrete construction... in which case there are answers here on MSE such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530651/construction-of-complex-numbers-inside-of-set-theory).

Comment: @zaemon_23 Well, then in your course you just assume its existence I guess. A more formal definition (which actually gives a construction) is to define a complex number as an ordered pair $(a,b)$ of real numbers. Define multiplication by $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac-bd, ad+bc)$. We denote $(a,b)=a+ib$, this is just a notation. In particular, $i$ is defined to be the ordered pair $(0,1)$. By direct computation we see that $i^2=-1$.

Comment: @zaemon_23, $\;\left(\Bbb C,+,\cdot\right)\,$ is the algebraic structure you get by defining the following two operations on the set $\,\Bbb C=\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\,.\;$ $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$;  $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$. In the algebraic structure $\;\left(\Bbb C,+,\cdot\right)\;$ there exists $\;i=(0,1)\,$ such that $\;i^2=(0,1)\cdot(0,1)=(-1,0)$. Since there exists an isomorphism between $\;R^*=\{(a,0)\,|\,a\in\Bbb R\}\,$ and $\,\Bbb R\,,\,$ we have got an element $\,i=(0,1)\,$ such that $\,i^2=-1\,.\,$

Comment: There seems to be somewhat of a conceptual misunderstanding here. You should stop thinking about mathematical objects "existing" and start thinking about mathematical objects being "well defined". We can define the complex numbers and operations on them in a perfectly consistent way, and that is enough for a mathematician. Whether or not the complex numbers exist in the same sense as atoms, or the number 7, is not something that mathematicians really care about, or something that can easily be discussed (although these discussions do sometimes happen in the realm of philosophy).

Comment: @C-RAM Excellent and very important comment ! Theoretical physicists unfortunately ignore this crucial part.

Comment: There are deep pholosophical volumes published about whether mathematical objects like numbers "exist".

Comment: Thank you C-RAM. I think i finally get it!

Answer (score 1):

The two statements about existence of the numbers $\sqrt2$ and $i$ seem to be of different types.

For $i$, you are asking is there a complex number that corresponds to $\sqrt{-1}$. But if you want to say what the set of complex numbers is, you say there is an object $i$ so $i^2=-1$ and the complex numbers are all objects of the form $a+bi$ where $a,b$ are real numbers and then you define arithmetic on the complex numbers to get a field. Here $i$ is built into the definition, so you know $i$ exists and is a square root of $-1$.

On the other hand, when you are asking about the existence of $\sqrt2$, you are asking is there a real number whose square is 2. And when you say what the real numbers are, they are the complete ordered field. This definition has nothing to do with $\sqrt2$, so it is a real question to ask if among these objects you defined, is there one whose square is 2. (You know 2 is a real number since it has to include all integers.)

So besides the fact that existence of non-physical numbers can be a complicated thing to talk about, the two  statements of existence are very different in the content they contain.

Comment: Non-physical numbers?

Comment: By non-physical I mean like C-RAM mentions in his comment about more philosophical, metaphysical questions such as what *is* -1 or 1/2, let alone $\sqrt2$ or $i$.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, so maybe this is too philosophical to me.